# Problems with query in Graphql - Unexpected EOF Error

Tags: javascript, graphql

I've set a Schema to make a GraphQL Query, and now I run the server, go to GraphQL Client, and I get the following error:

"Syntax Error: Unexpected "

line: 32.

My code is the following:

```
const graphql = require('graphql') const _ = require('lodash') const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLSchema
} = graphql;
const users = [{
  id: '23',
  firstName: 'Thiago',
  age: 36
}, {
  id: '47',
  firstName: 'Caroline',
  age: 29
}];

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    firstName: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    age: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    }
  }
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return _.find(users, {
          id: args.id
        })
      }
    }
  }
}) module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That is an issue with the query you're sending, not with your schema.

Comment: But what to do to solve it?

Comment: You can edit your question with the actual query being sent and any relevant client code. Otherwise, there's no way to tell what the actual issue is.